# How can I move the stdout of a Python program to a file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, batch-file, cmd

I'm using Python 2.7, and I'm on Windows 7 right now, but I'm usually on Linux, so an answer for UNIX-like systems would be much appreciated as well.

I know that one can push standard output to files in many UNIX-like systems with the following command:

```
hello_world.py > hello_world_output.txt
```

That puts all of the standard output of `hello_world.py` into `hello_world_output.txt`. Based on what I just tried five seconds ago, this command appears to work the same way on Windows systems.

But say I have a single program with many Python files, and I want to push all of their standard output to a certain `output.txt`, or `log.txt`, etc. How can I do this? I've tried the command `main.py > output.txt`, but that only pushes the standard output of `main.py`, not the rest of my `.py` files as well.

In both Linux and Windows systems, how can I push the standard output of multiple-file programs (including but not limited to Python programs) to a single file? I am familiar with BASH so I am inherently somewhat literate with batch-file lingo, too.

---

### Update

The one line command above works on my Linux system. I guess the problem has to do with my program's process management on Windows systems.

Comment: One thing that you can do in python 3 is print to a file object. For example, if you have output that needs to be pushed to a file, do `print(args, file=f1)`. This functionality is in the `__future__` module and can be imported to python 2.7.

Comment: @gjdanis Thank you, but I want to use standard output to do this stuff. --- I don't want to have to modify any code. I also don't mean to be specific to Python; I would like to do this with other languages, too.

Comment: What are you doing in main.py to run the other files?

Comment: @Wooble I am importing them and calling their functions, creating their objects, etc. In some of those files I print stuff that I would like to put in `output.txt`.

Comment: I have a feeling he is doing something like `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: @user3745189: unless the files themselves are doing something weird to output text, what you're describing should definitely work. Show a short, self-contained example where this fails.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah I think you're right. Here's what I said in response to someone else: "...using the original one-line command [on Linux] works as well so I think the problem is actually just something dumb about my program's process management on Windows, so standard out gets all screwed up."

Answer (score 1):

For bash it should be as simple as grouping the scripts into a list (if run from the shell individually) and redirecting the group `{ ... } > out.txt`.

```
$ { echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } > out.txt
$ cat out.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

If the python script itself runs the other python scripts then that shouldn't even be necessary as they should all inherit the `stdout` redirection from the parent python process.

I have no idea if Windows can do the former or works the same with respect to the latter but it might (or might be possible at least).

Comment: Yeah this is working on my Linux system. But using the original one-line command works as well so I think the problem is actually just something dumb about my program's process management on Windows, so standard out gets all screwed up.

Comment: Like I said Windows may not have the `stdout` inheritance behaviour that linux does. So your scripts-run-by-python may not be seeing the redirection. How are you running the scripts?